# Is it possible to group sections of an API with rustdoc?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

Is it possible to group sections of an API? related functions, types or constants for example.

Doxygen for example supports [grouping like this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html):

```
/** \name Some API Grouping
 * \{ */

// code //

/* \} */
```

Is rustdoc capable of something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Would be nice, but sadly no.

**Edit**: As noted by Matthieu M., you *can* add doc comments to individual `impl` blocks, but that doesn't solve the general case.

Comment: What of the fact that the methods are grouped per `impl`? It's implicit but is already some form of grouping.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That *does* work for methods (since you can attach docs to `impl`s), but it doesn't help for free functions, types, or constants.

Comment: Yes, better than nothing :)